# Recommendations for "How to model X", "How to do X" (X an informal task)

Tags: discussion, faq

It would be nice to have a set of general recommendations and requirements for users asking "[How to model X](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-modeling)", "[Applications of theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-of-theory)", and "How to do X" questions where X is an informal task (i.e. not stated in a clear mathematically rigorous way). Having such a list of recommendations and requirements would help the OPs of those post in improving the quality of their question and make it easier for others to answer them.

MathOverflow has a set of general suggestions on its "[How to ask](https://mathoverflow.net/howtoask)" page, and we also have some other [general suggestions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq#questions-should-be-based-on-knowledge-sharing-not-on-shirking) in our [FAQ](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq). If you have any suggestion please post it below as an answer.

---

Related meta-discussions:

- [How-to-model-this questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/514/how-to-model-this-questions)
- [How to deal with "How to do X?" questions where X is a very high-level (software engineering) task](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/how-to-deal-with-how-to-do-x-questions-where-x-is-a-very-high-level-software)

I have created a [wiki](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/formal-modeling/info) for formal-modeling tag.

Comment: [Scott Aaronson's answer][1] is a good template. 


  [1]: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/514/how-to-model-this-questions/519#519